# strtok with space delimiter

Tags: c, strtok

hey i am trying to use the strtok function in C with " " as a delimiter and for some reason it does not work.
can some one please tell me how to parse using strtok with a space as a delimiter
thanks in advance

Comment: Show us your code. (and read the documentation for strtok)

Comment: "for some reason it does not work", is not descriptive or helpful.  What did you expect it to do?  What does it actually do?  What debugging steps have you tried?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Stolen (and slightly modified) from [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strtok/).

```
/* strtok example */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
  char str[] ="- This, a sample string.";
  char * pch;
  printf ("Splitting string \"%s\" into tokens:\n",str);
  pch = strtok (str," ");
  while (pch != NULL)
  {
    printf ("%s\n",pch);
    pch = strtok (NULL, " ");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use tab "\t"  or use both " \t" ie. space and tab both...see if it works