# Reversing a Series of Strings

Tags: c

I am having a problem where my series of strings does not print out the way I want it. It only prints out the last string and reverses the last string, but not any of the strings before that. Can anyone help me out, please?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void reverse(char strings[80], int start, int end);
int main (void){

  char strings[80];

  printf("\tEnter a string to reverse: \n");
  while( scanf ("%s", strings) !=EOF);

  reverse(strings, 0, strlen(strings)-1);
  printf("\tThe reverse strings: \n%s\n",strings);

return 0;}
void reverse(char strings[80], int start, int end)
{
  char A;
  if (start >= end)
  return;

  A = *(strings+start);
  *(strings+start) = *(strings+end);
  *(strings+end) = A;

  reverse (strings, ++start, --end);
}
```

Comment: I'm just guessing here, that `while( scanf ("%s", strings) !=EOF);`, which scans strings until EOF *without doing **anything** with them and overwriting the last with the next* is not exactly helping.

Comment: What happens if you type 80 'A' characters into the console?

Answer (score 1):

Your calls to reverse() and printf() aren't inside the while loop, so they are only called once each (for the last string that is read).

It should be

```
while (scanf ("%s", strings) != EOF)
{
    reverse(strings, 0, strlen(strings)-1);
    printf("\tThe reverse strings: \n%s\n",strings);
}
```

Comment: Well actually this will print every line you enter in reverse until you CTRL-D (EOF), but I'm not sure if that is actually what you are trying to do.

Comment: Ive tried it. This time it changes the part where it only allows me to type in one string. Im confused?

Comment: It suppose to ask at first to print a series of strings that the user wants to reverse. Then reverse those strings. Originally without the EOF input, it would only accept one string.

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do. If you are trying to read in a bunch of strings separated by spaces, have to split them all up using `strtok()`

Comment: The problem is that when you have scanf("%s", strings) it is treating the entire line as a whole string, since the spaces are still characters included in the string.

Comment: Oh ok. So with the scanf(), I replace it with strtok() and it'll solve the issue? (sorry for not clarifying the issue)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4160273/strtok-with-space-delimiter

Using the answer from the linked question, you could use your original code and replace `printf()` from the example with your own calls to `reverse()` and `printf()`