# How do I use strtok to take in words separated by white space into a char array in C?

Tags: c, file, unix, input, strtok

I have opened a file as such:

```
#define MAX 1000000000
char buffer[MAX];

FILE *file = fopen("sample1.txt", "r");
char c;


if(file == NULL) {
    perror("File open error");
    return -1;
}
```

Now what I want to do is that use 'strtok' and take in seperate words from the file into the char array buffer.

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried?

Comment: First you need to use `fgets` or `fgetc` or `fscanf` to read stuff from the file.

Comment: `static char buffer[MAX];`

Comment: there is  'a rat' in separate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you seem new here, I will answer, but make sure to put more effort on your next question in SO.

Did you search for `strtok()`? In the [ref](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/), there is a very nice example. I just modified it a bit to use only the whitespace as a token.

I will leave the integration of this code to your code for you.

```
/* strtok example with whitespaces*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
  char str[] ="- This, a sample string.";
  char * pch;
  printf ("Splitting string \"%s\" into token:\n",str);
  pch = strtok (str," ");
  while (pch != NULL)
  {
    printf ("%s\n",pch);
    pch = strtok (NULL, " ");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Also notice that you can search google for relevant problems to yours. Here is a relevant [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4160273/strtok-with-space-delimiter)!

---

As Alter Mann pointed out:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *strsep(char **, const char *);

int main(void)
{
    char str[] = "- This, a sample string.";
    char *pch = str;
    char *tok;

    printf("Splitting string \"%s\" into token:\n", str);
    while (tok = strsep(&pch, " \t\n")) {
        printf("%s\n", tok);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

is what you are looking for, is not standard but its available on many implementations. Check its ref [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strsep.3.html).

Moreover, notice how this is a tip for improving the `strtok()` code I provided above.

Comment: this does space (' ') not whitespace as asked for

Comment: Of course I would do that @Serdalis ;) I was just checking to see if the code is displayed accordingly!

Comment: @pm100 I am not sure what I have to change I admit.

Comment: thats OK - its a test for the OP

Comment: `strsep(&ptr, " \t\n");` is what you are looking for, is not standard but its available on many implementations, [take a look](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strsep.3.html)

Comment: Very good @AlterMann. Would you mind if I edited the answer with that?

Comment: @G.Samaras, of course, feel free to edit your post ;)

Comment: I agree @pm100. Alter Mann's comment gave me the opportunity to give a strong tip to the OP, without giving fully the code (well...not really, but it's something).